# Stop Hibernate SQL logs coming on catalina.out

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, orm, catalina.out

I was making a log4j.xml for one of my projects in netbeans .
Here is its contents :

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MyLogs.log" />
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m #]%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

    <appender name="sqlLogs" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MySqlLogs.log" />
            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>    

    <root>
            <level value ="INFO" />    
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false" >
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="sqlLogs" />
    </logger>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Now i want sql logs to go only to MySqlLogs.log but they are appearing on both MySqlLogs.log and catalina.out .
The format of logs in catalina.out is

```
Hibernate : select ....
Hibernate : insert into ....
```

Can anyone help me out on this please .

Comment: Is `hibernate.show_sql` turned off?

Comment: Yes i had already turned it off in persistence.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop it, on your env shared properties.

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: This fixed the problem :                                                                              p:showsql="false" in applicationcontext   Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you have to add the following line in your hibernate_cfg.xml file

```
show_sql to false
```

and in your file loging.properties :

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace

log4j.logger.org.apache=debug
```

Comment: Bedjaoui, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).